# MS Access Form - Enter key not moving to new line

Tags: forms, ms-access, return, carriage-return

I have an odd issue with a form I have in MS Access. For some reason, when I hit the "enter" key within a text box, the cursor moves to a different text box. What i am looking to happen is for the cursor to simply move to another line within the same text box.

Anyone have any ideas how to correct this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter a new line into any text box.

For a specific text box, you can make the <kbd>Enter</kbd> insert a new line instead of moving to another control on the form by changing the text box's *Enter Key Behavior* property.

[image: text box Enter Key Behavior property]

That's what I think you're actually looking for, but you would need to set that property for every text box where you want it to happen ... which may be fine for your needs.  I mentioned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> first only because that method works for any text box without changing the default property setting.

Comment: now that it is 2019, is there any universal settings that are better?

Comment: Sorry I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

Under file, options, client settings, very first one option move after enter and change from next field to next record.